# How many binary sequences are there with $s$ zeros and $t$ ones?

Tags: probability

> How many binary sequences are there with $s$ zeros and $t$ ones? For
>   example, given,
>
> $$10101110$$
>
> then $s=3$ and $t=5$.

Solution:

I think the answer is

\begin{align}
    \binom{s+t}{t}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. For given $s$ and $t$ any binary sequence with $s$ zeros and $t$ ones has $s+t$ digits. Now there are $\binom{s+t}{t}$ possible choices for the positions of the $t$ ones (this is just the combinatorical interpretation of the binomial coefficient).